# Efficient row-wise operation (aggregation) based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, dataframe

I am working on a large dataset, and need to combine certain columns into a list. The challenge is, the number of columns chosen, is subject to another key value, which is different for every row.

### Example:

#### Original dataset:

```
Key Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 NonrelatedCols
1   a    b    c    d    e    ...
3   r    b    x    d    c    ...
2   k    d    q    l    w    ...
0   w    a    c    s    w    ...
```

#### Expected outcome:

```
Key  List      NonrelatedCols
1    [a]       ...
3    [r,b,x]   ...
2    [k,d]     ...
0    []        ...
```

The main challenge is on the performance of the code. Iterate through the rows, is not the optimum approach, and I am looking for a more efficient way.

I tried to selecting only the targeted columns, and then use the `agg(list,axis=1)` function. The issue is, there is no way to aggregate the columns, based on key values. It seems, I still have to perform iteration through all the rows, and then drop the excessive values in the combined column

```
Cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3','Col4','Col5']
CombinedList = rawData[Cols].agg(list,axis=1)
for i in range(rawData.shape[0]):
    CombinedList[i]=CombinedList[i][:rawData['Key'][i]]
```

To sum up, is there way to simplify the code, so I do not need to iterate through all the rows?

Answer (score 2):

Consider only the columns of importance:

```
    Key Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
0    1    a    b    c    d    e
1    3    r    b    x    d    c
2    2    k    d    q    l    w
3    0    w    a    c    s    w
```

Assuming `Key` is always in the first column, `apply` the `list` function to all `Col` columns of interest except the first (`Key`), then index the list according to the value in `Key`:

```
df.apply(lambda x : list(x[1:])[:x[0]], axis=1)
```

- This requires `Key` to be an `int`

  - If `Key` is not an `int`, then use `df = df.astype({'Key': 'int32'})`

Output:

```
0          [a]
1    [r, b, x]
2       [k, d]
3           []
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[1:x.Key+1].tolist(), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0          [a]
1    [r, b, x]
2       [k, d]
3           []
dtype: object
```

Comment: Is `df.apply` any faster than a more explicit row iteration, or is just more convenience.  I know some `numpy` 'apply' functions are just convenience tools.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't think `df.apply` with axis=1 is any faster just convenient.